# How to get datasets into kaggle

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dataset, kaggle

I have two .csv files named as `train_data.csv` and `resources.csv`. I want to use these two files on a `kaggle kernel`. Both of these files are present on my google drive. My question is: How do I get these files into my kaggle kernel without downloading them from my google drive and re-uploading them onto the kernel. Is there a way to do so?

if no:

Another question, how do I create datasets from remote URLs? Because kaggle gives us an option to do so, I Just wanna know how do I do it

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[This video shows you how to upload data in a kernel](https://youtu.be/0jQwAp7po00). Unless your data is publicly accessible you can't currently create a data from its URL.

You can create datasets from URLs that point directly at a file. Sometimes you may see errors if there's a mismatch between the HTML metadata and what Kaggle looks for.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Kaggle provides 4 options to upload your dataset into a kernel. The 2nd one allows you to use a url.

This method cannot be used in submission kernel.